# Execute an Ant script from other Ant script?

Tags: scripting, ant

I have several Ant scripts, for example ant1.xml, ant2.xml, ant3.xml. And I want to execute ant1.xml and ant2.xml in ant3.xml, so that when I execute ant3.xml, ant1.xml and ant2.xml are executed.

Can anyone show me some ways, please?

Answer (score 5):

Import ant1.xml and ant2.xml in ant3.xml by using an import or include command

```
<import file="ant1.xml"/>
```

Set the intended targets in ant1 and ant2 as a default - example below

```
<project default="compile-ant1">

<project default="compile-ant2">
```

This will run from within ant3 as required.

See here for more details: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html

Comment: @martin clayton: thanks for edit. i'm sure the link was working when i posted it first